# Table returned by ajax request not displayed properly

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I do an ajax request which returns a html table. When I just do a location redirect to that page the table is displayed properly but when I put the ajax response inside a div element, the table goes out of shape.

```
function submitQuery() {
  length = category_query.length;
  if(category_query.indexOf('ALL') != -1)
    category_query = category_query.substring(0,length-4);    
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      document.getElementById('resultDiv1').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
  } 
  xmlhttp.open("GET","cons_query.php?q="+category_query,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
  //window.location="cons_query.php?q="+category_query;
  //if i just redirect to this location, the table is displayed fine.
}
```

I want the table to look as it is even through ajax.

Comment: Use jQuery for easier AJAX requests.

Comment: make sure the table get it style

Comment: @COLDTOLD how to get its style?

Comment: One approach would be to have the css for the table already in the page with the ajax call. One suggestion I have for you is to send json object through ajax, not full dom elements.

Comment: reference the style on the page you getting the table

Comment: @Angel I already tried putting the css in this page where i put size of rows and columns but the lines dividing the columns are missing. how to get those back?

Comment: @COLDTOLD the table is getting the style from the other page like the color and all but it is distorted

Comment: Can we see some code samples?

Comment: Does the page cons_query.php?q=XXXXXXX contiain anything else than the table? Like <html> and <body> tags?

Comment: @geon yeah it has some tags and some css style.Will removing them solve the problem?

Comment: @user1505986 Possibly. If there is anything there that shouldn't be in the div, it will probably not display properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm... looks like you are floating the row elements left side in your response page.
Just remove that formatting from css
It should look something like this
td { width: <>px; float: left; }